Quarkus is not finding some aws classes when trying to use Neptune
I am trying to create a quarkus rest server that will be able to connect to aws Neptune.
However, when I try to connect in native mode I get this error
{
    "timestamp": "2024-11-08T23:49:54.81157Z",
    "sequence": 369,
    "loggerClassName": "org.jboss.logging.Logger",
    "loggerName": "io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.QuarkusErrorHandler",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "HTTP Request to /hello failed, error id: fd3b301f-4ddf-40c5-b39f-1bb9c1f666d7-6",
    "threadName": "executor-thread-1",
    "threadId": 34,
    "mdc": {
        "spanId": "a62b25d51c63a137",
        "traceId": "249fd6227268326bbd5529aa3561afb8",
        "sampled": "true"
    },
    "ndc": "",
    "hostName": "visitor-identity-platform-api-106-x2mmw-s2vtg-c8fnq",
    "processId": 399,
    "exception": {
        "refId": 1,
        "exceptionType": "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError",
        "message": "software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpService: Provider software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.AwsCrtSdkHttpService not found",
        "frames": [
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader",
                "method": "fail",
                "line": 593
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator",
                "method": "nextProviderClass",
                "line": 1219
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator",
                "method": "hasNextService",
                "line": 1228
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator",
                "method": "hasNext",
                "line": 1273
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader$2",
                "method": "hasNext",
                "line": 1309
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ServiceLoader$3",
                "method": "hasNext",
                "line": 1393
            },
            {
                "class": "java.lang.Iterable",
                "method": "forEach",
                "line": 74
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.ClasspathSdkHttpServiceProvider",
                "method": "loadService",
                "line": 74
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1",
                "method": "accept",
                "line": 197
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator",
                "method": "tryAdvance",
                "line": 1002
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline",
                "method": "forEachWithCancel",
                "line": 129
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline",
                "method": "copyIntoWithCancel",
                "line": 527
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline",
                "method": "copyInto",
                "line": 513
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline",
                "method": "wrapAndCopyInto",
                "line": 499
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp",
                "method": "evaluateSequential",
                "line": 150
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline",
                "method": "evaluate",
                "line": 234
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline",
                "method": "findFirst",
                "line": 647
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.SdkHttpServiceProviderChain",
                "method": "loadService",
                "line": 44
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.CachingSdkHttpServiceProvider",
                "method": "loadService",
                "line": 46
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder",
                "method": "buildWithDefaults",
                "line": 40
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "lambda$resolveSyncHttpClient$14",
                "line": 398
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.Optional",
                "method": "orElseGet",
                "line": 364
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "resolveSyncHttpClient",
                "line": 398
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "lambda$finalizeSyncConfiguration$2",
                "line": 285
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$DerivedValue",
                "method": "primeCache",
                "line": 600
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$DerivedValue",
                "method": "get",
                "line": 589
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$Builder",
                "method": "resolveValue",
                "line": 396
            },
            {
                "class": "java.util.ArrayList",
                "method": "forEach",
                "line": 1511
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap$Builder",
                "method": "build",
                "line": 362
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.config.SdkClientConfiguration$Builder",
                "method": "build",
                "line": 232
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "finalizeSyncConfiguration",
                "line": 287
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "syncClientConfiguration",
                "line": 189
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptunedata.DefaultNeptunedataClientBuilder",
                "method": "buildClient",
                "line": 37
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptunedata.DefaultNeptunedataClientBuilder",
                "method": "buildClient",
                "line": 25
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder",
                "method": "build",
                "line": 155
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.identity.database.NeptuneClientProducer",
                "method": "getWriterClient",
                "line": 29
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.identity.database.NeptuneClientProducer_ProducerMethod_getWriterClient_mZspEn1oE8yIjJLnopTKxWG32Wg_Bean",
                "method": "doCreate"
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.identity.database.NeptuneClientProducer_ProducerMethod_getWriterClient_mZspEn1oE8yIjJLnopTKxWG32Wg_Bean",
                "method": "create"
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.identity.database.NeptuneClientProducer_ProducerMethod_getWriterClient_mZspEn1oE8yIjJLnopTKxWG32Wg_Bean",
                "method": "create"
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext",
                "method": "createInstanceHandle",
                "line": 119
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1",
                "method": "get",
                "line": 38
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1",
                "method": "get",
                "line": 35
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.generator.Default_jakarta_enterprise_context_ApplicationScoped_ContextInstances",
                "method": "c16"
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.generator.Default_jakarta_enterprise_context_ApplicationScoped_ContextInstances",
                "method": "computeIfAbsent"
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext",
                "method": "get",
                "line": 35
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies",
                "method": "getApplicationScopedDelegate",
                "line": 21
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptunedata.NeptuneClientProducer_ProducerMethod_getWriterClient_mZspEn1oE8yIjJLnopTKxWG32Wg_ClientProxy",
                "method": "arc$delegate"
            },
            {
                "class": "software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptunedata.NeptuneClientProducer_ProducerMethod_getWriterClient_mZspEn1oE8yIjJLnopTKxWG32Wg_ClientProxy",
                "method": "executeOpenCypherQuery"
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.IdentityResource",
                "method": "testIdentityService",
                "line": 68
            },
            {
                "class": "com.company.gateway.company.IdentityResource$quarkusrestinvoker$testIdentityService_ca95d942b9cf97c6c52a4e04f7ffdf8168688dec",
                "method": "invoke"
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler",
                "method": "handle",
                "line": 29
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext",
                "method": "invokeHandler",
                "line": 141
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 147
            },
            {
                "class": "io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14",
                "method": "runWith",
                "line": 582
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 2513
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 1538
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 29
            },
            {
                "class": "org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 29
            },
            {
                "class": "io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 30
            },
            {
                "class": "java.lang.Thread",
                "method": "run",
                "line": 833
            },
            {
                "class": "com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads",
                "method": "threadStartRoutine",
                "line": 807
            },
            {
                "class": "com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads",
                "method": "pthreadStartRoutine",
                "line": 210
            }
        ]
    }
}

Here is is my pom.xml
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.9.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>3.8.4</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.8.4</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <skipIntegrationTests>true</skipIntegrationTests>
    <allure-maven.version>2.12.0</allure-maven.version>
    <allure-junit5.version>2.23.0</allure-junit5.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.19</aspectj.version>
    <aws.java.sdk.version>2.25.7</aws.java.sdk.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.28</slf4j.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-services-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-micrometer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-logging-json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-opentelemetry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.project-openubl</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-bouncycastle-deployment</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkiverse.amazonservices</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-amazon-kms</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>netty-nio-client</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-crt-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>neptunedata</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>ssooidc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>url-connection-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.20</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jacoco</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
      <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
      <version>20.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
      <version>${allure-junit5.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

I am not sure how to get past this problem. I trying to get the classes registered using the pom.xml and also using the quarkus.native.additional-build-args= but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Has anyone seen this problem before?
This is my current deploy command that is run in jenkins
mvn deploy -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.additional-build-args='--initialize-at-run-time=javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier\,com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEG\$JCS\,org.apache.http.impl.auth.NTLMEngineImpl\,software.amazon.awssdk.utils.cache.CachedSupplier\,com.company.model.DeleteEventsResponse\,com.company.model.GetEventsResponse\,com.company.model.EventUrl\,com.company.model.EventData\,com.company.model.TagData\,com.company.model.Event\,software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssooidc.SsoOidcTokenProviderFactory\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl\,org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable\,software.amazon.awssdk.http.crt.AwsCrtSdkHttpService\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.ClasspathSdkHttpServiceProvider\,software.amazon.awssdk.http.SdkHttpService\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.SdkHttpServiceProviderChain\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.CachingSdkHttpServiceProvider\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder\,software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptunedata.DefaultNeptunedataClientBuilder\,com.company.gateway.company.identity.database.NeptuneClientProducer\,software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap\,software.amazon.awssdk.utils.AttributeMap\,software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.interceptor.HttpChecksumRequiredInterceptor\,software.amazon.awssdk.services.ssooidc.SsoOidcTokenProviderFactory,-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflect-config.json,--allow-incomplete-classpath'

